# Debug jbpm processes

Tags: maven, jbpm

I'm currently working with JBpm Kie. We have processes with custom workitem (and custom work item handlers code). We find very difficult to debug our code as our workItem handlers are mainly asynchronous and completed via REST api.
I read that workItem handlers can be provided to KIE engine through a maven repository (I'm very new to Maven). . Id' love to know if I can configure my PC as Maven repository and to debug my code as it is requested by jBpm processes. Is it possible?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want. If you want to run a Maven repository on your PC, you can install Nexus or Artifactory.

Comment: I'd like to debug code as it is served by maven but I actually don't know if it makes any sense.

Comment: You probably need to add more information to your question so that we understand what you want to do (please edit the question instead of adding comments for that).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you talking about the feature to provide your own workitem repository. Which is described here in more detail: http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2018/07/easy-workitem-installation-jbpm.html

But please note that this won‘t solve your request for debugging your workitemhandler code. This can be archived with writing Unittests (easy) or by putting them into a spring boot jbpm starter project and run it there (hard).
BTW: the last option is used by the JBPM project themself to test there Product.

Comment: If you are interested in creating process models together with workitemhandler which are unittestable checkout: https://github.com/Arvato-Systems/kie4developer